# Protect wired connections to Belkin router

Tags: security

I want to prevent users from accessing the Internet through a wired connection to my router. How do I protect this?

I have a Belkin G+ MIMO 4-port Router with the following version info:

```
Firmware Version  1.00.02 (Jul 31 2008 22:32:20)
Boot Version      V0.13         
Hardware          F5D9231-4v1(01)   
Serial No.      12838923107956
```

Comment: well, if you'll *never* need to use them you could fill them with resin or take cut off or un-used cable ends and glue them into the ports. but that may be a little extreme

Comment: just fill your LAN-Ports with hot glue or silicone ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could lock the router in a box, with holes cut out for the antennae and hard-wired internet connection. Of course, someone could always just unplug your router from the wall and plug their computer directly on the internet port. So unless you're going to keep the router in a locked room, or put some sort of locking cover/cabinet over the internet port in the wall, this may be an exercise in futility.

Answer (score 1):

What we do at work is put the router in a locked room (that's where are intenet connection resides). Voila, no wired access.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you might consider turning off the DHCP on your router, then set the IP address scheme to something a little strange - say 192.168.55.15 for the internal IP address.  If they don't know the address scheme and don't know the gateway address, that should stop them.

Comment: This is interesting. How would this affect wireless users?

Comment: Same.  They may see your SSID, but without DHCP, they would have to know how to manually configure their IP settings to get in and would need to know what IP address the gateway is at and what IP scheme to use.

Comment: Note that this will not work if you use no (or crackable) encryption since the IPs and MAcs will be sent over the air and can be picked up by anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're looking for a software option, you could try using a domain on your network, and only allow network or Internet access from the domain. In order to join the domain, you'd need a username/password, making anonymous access not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Look for MAC filtering in your router's settings. It's by any means not a foolproof method, but normal users won't know what to do.
Just add a list of allowed MAC (all devices you want to allow to connect through a wire) and block all others.

Comment: This may depend on the router. In my old Linksys, and my new Netgear, the MAC filter is specific just to the wireless connections. There is no MAC filter section for wired connections.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/16279/physical-port-locks-for-ethernet-usb-phone-etc/16282#16282) mentions [RJLockdown](http://shop.willyselectronics.com/browse.cfm/rj45lock-jack-i-rj45-jack-security-lock:-ivory-1-each-/4,10599.html) ([manufacturer](http://www.rjlockdown.com/)) which looks like it might be useful.

[image: RJLockdown]

Comment: This is interesting because the OP of the referenced post talks about disabling a port. Is there a software way to disable a TCP/IP port on the router?

Comment: @P23: The factory firmware doesn't seem to support this. If you can find alternative firmware that supports your model, you may be able to disable the ports or create a dead-end VLAN. While DD-WRT doesn't appear to support your model, [here is a discussion if its VLAN features](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Switched_Ports). They do support other Belkin models so you might see if future support is planned for yours.

Answer (score -1):

While not overly effective, you can block the average user from connecting via wired or wireless if you filter by MAC address.  If you want people to be able to access using wireless, then go with eidylon or xantec's suggestion.